# Derivation of Flory's Model for Linear Condensation of Polymers

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, polymers

I'm having some trouble understanding a part of Flory's model for linear polycondensation reactions. In his 1936 paper, he derives an expression for the probability of the existence of a particular $x$-mer as

> $$\Pi_x = xp^{x-1}(1 - p)^2\tag{2}$$

Later, he states the following:

> In order to locate the $x$ value which gives a maximum in $\Pi_x,$ let
>
> $$\partial\Pi_x/\partial x = (1 - p)^2(p^{x - 1} + xp^{x - 1}\ln p) = 0$$

Not being the most mathematically savvy person, can someone explain to me how he got to this expression?

#### Reference

1. Flory, P. J. Molecular Size Distribution in Linear Condensation Polymers. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1936**, 58 (10), 1877–1885. DOI: [10.1021/ja01301a016](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01301a016).

Comment: "Not being the most mathematically savvy person" - How much do you know about differentiation? Does https://www.mytutor.co.uk/answers/5998/A-Level/Maths/How-do-you-differentiate-a-x/  Make any sense? Do you know [the Product Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) for differentiation?

Comment: @Justus Have a look at my answer and if it answers your question, please click on the tick mark next to the answer. You also get +2 points on doing this :)

Answer (score 1):

Given $\Pi_{x}$= $*^{−1}$ *$(1−)^2$

$\partial$ refers to partial differentiation.

$\frac{\partial \Pi_{x}}{\partial x}$ means differentiating $\Pi_{x}$ with respect to x.

Therefore $(1−)^2$ is a constant when differentiating with respect to x.
So during differentiation the constant stays as a constant multiplier.

Now see that there are two terms involving x, therefore we need to use the [product rule of differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).

$\left(\frac{\partial \Pi_{x}}{\partial x}\right)$ =  $(1−)^2$ * ($^{−1}* \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + x*\frac{\partial p^{x-1}}{\partial x}$)

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$ = 1 and for calculating $\frac{\partial p^{x-1}}{\partial x}$ look at [exponentiation rule of differentiation](https://www.mytutor.co.uk/answers/5998/A-Level/Maths/How-do-you-differentiate-a-x/) as suggested by @Ian Bush in the comments.

Therefore we finally have :

$\left(\frac{\partial \Pi_{x}}{\partial x}\right)$ =  $(1−)^2$ * ($^{−1}* 1 + x*ln(p)*p^{x-1}$)

And since he is trying to locate the  value which gives a maximum in $\Pi_{x}$, he equates the equation to 0.

$\left(\frac{\partial \Pi_{x}}{\partial x}\right)$ =  $(1−)^2$ * ($^{−1}* 1 + x*ln(p)*p^{x-1}$) = 0